# What is the difference between an alpha subunit and a non-alpha subunit in ACh receptors?

Tags: neuroanatomy

When reading about ACh receptors, it is frequently the case that a protein is described as (alpha) or (non-alpha).  However, I haven't really been able to find out what that means.  What is the difference, and why would it matter if a subunit is alpha or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achetylcholine (ACh) receptor is a pentamer of two [alpha](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/F8WDS3) chains, and one each of the [beta](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/I3L535), [delta](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q07001), and [gamma](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/P07510) (in immature muscle) or [epsilon](http://www.uniprot.org/uniprot/Q04844) (in mature muscle) chains.

Comment: I see. So is it called alpha simply because there are always two when the others are only one?

Comment: an alpha subunit is alpha; a non-alpha subunit is beta, gamma, delta, or epsilon.

Comment: I fear that still doesn't clarify.  The subunits are different proteins, is that right?  That being the case, is there anything special about alpha?  I assume so, since the sub units are grouped as "alpha" and "non-alpha", implying that alpha has special status, doesn't it?

Comment: The alpha subunit contains the acetylcholine binding site. Lyddiatt et al. (1979) FEBS Lett 108: 20-24 (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/520545); Sumikawa et al. (1982) Nucl Acids Res 10: 5809-5822 (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6183641).